# Magento shopping cart rule exclusion logic

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, shopping-cart-price-rules

I am trying to create a shopping cart rule which excludes special price products

I have set the condition as below

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
If an item is NOT FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true: 
Special Price  greater than  0

It works fine when I add a regular price product in the cart, the discount is applied, but if I add a regular priced product and special priced product, the coupon shows up as invalid.

I would like the coupon to be applied to the regular priced product and exclude the special priced product

What is the right condition for this logic?

UPDATE:

I have narrowed the issue to only bundled products, I am not able to apply any rules to bundled products, magento only applies the rule to the individual items in a bundle, how to make magento apply the rule to the bundle instead of the items in the bundle?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, what you want is to apply a rule only to products found in the cart that don't have a special price.

Leave your "Conditions" Tab Empty (or put anything else in it) and then go to the "Actions" Tab and add your logic to

"Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)"

Comment: I tried excluding bundled products but for some reason it won't work, I tried product type attribute and SKU (where I mentioned one bundled product SKU for testing the rule)